# mysql change innodb_large_prefix

Tags: mysql, innodb, utf8mb4

I just setup debian 8.3 on a VM and installed xampp after this [Tutorial](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/xampp.htm). Everything is working, until I tried to create a new table:

```
create table testtable
(
  id int(10) not null auto_increment,
  firstname varchar(255) collate utf8mb4_german2_ci not null,
  lastname varchar(255) collate utf8mb4_german2_ci not null,
  primary key (id),
  unique key (lastname)
)engine = innodb default charset=utf8mb4, collate=utf8mb4_german2_ci
```

I got the error: `#1709 - Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.`
Then I found out this comes from the `prefix limitation` which is limited to 767Byte in `Innodb` and I can fix this by set the innodb_large_prefix in the my.cnf file. But I can't find the file, its not under `/etc/` and theres no `/etc/mysql/`-folder, the only `my.cnf` I found is in `/opt/lampp/etc/`, however, after I added the `innodb_large_prefix=1` to the file and restarted lampp. I stil get the same error. What did I do wrong?

**edit**: `SELECT version()` returns `5.6.14`, so `innodb_large_prefix` should be supported.

**edit2**: I know I can work around this by only set part of the the key as index to get under 767Byte. But I want to know here how to config the mysql correctly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Between 5.6.3 and 5.7.7 (that is if you are running MySQL 5.6 or MariaDB 10.0), there are 4 steps:

- SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
- SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=ON;
- ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC; -- or COMPRESSED (goes on end of CREATE)
- innodb_large_prefix=1

**Note**

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES;
```

will provide the file_format and row_format. Some other I_S tables provide clues of file_per_table.

Comment: Its not very clear where I should put these, in the `my.cnf` file I found in the `/opt/lampp/etc/` folder? I saw some suggestions where they put `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` in the `engine` line, but it did't solve the problem for me.

Comment: running `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_fil%'` give me the result that `innodb_file_per_table` is on already. So I added the line `innodb_file_format=Barracuda` (without SET GLOBAL) and `innodb_large_prefix=1`to the `my.cnf` file and `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` to the end of CREATE. And its working! Thank you very much. One thing, will the file_format change have any effect on my existing data?

Comment: No.  All of those settings are captured as a table is created.  (You could change existing tables using ALTER.)  I added a Note.

Comment: Dear Mr. Downvoter:  If there is a flaw in my Answer, please tell me; I'll fix it.

Answer (score 16):

I'm using Mysql 5.6.17 with WAMP Server
I solved the problem by editing the my.ini file
Find the category [mysqld] there add the following instructions

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_large_prefix = 1
innodb_file_per_table = ON
```

Don't forget to save the changes and restart all services.

Comment: Does this change the file format of exisiting Tables?

Answer (score 13):

For a permanent solution, pls add following in your mariadb My.INI file-

```
## Innodb settings to bypass error of max size 737
innodb-file-format=barracuda
innodb-file-per-table=ON
innodb-large-prefix=ON
## Above 3 didnot work so i added below
innodb_default_row_format = 'DYNAMIC'
```

I was using 10.1.38

Comment: Thank you. This is the only answer that worked for me :) Spent a whole day on this.

Comment: Maybe you should link to *why* this is: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-row-format.html

Comment: I spent about 12hrs trying to figure out the 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes error and also tried so many options over there including the Schema::defaultStringLength(191); and this solution fix the issue, THANKS!. And by the way don't forget to restart MySQL and Apache Server :-)

Comment: THANK YOU!! I put these under [server] so as not to mess up the client when you want to use that.

I also commented out the row format bit, because it wasn't working, but I believe it is a table-level thing fundamentally and it looks like the gitea convert routine I was using was smart enough to handle that part because I didn't have to apply that change myself to the tables.

(was having an error "Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes") https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/issues/13588

Answer (score 4):

Go to your xampp and add this query:

```
`mysql>` set global innodb_file_format = `BARRACUDA`;
`mysql>` set global innodb_large_prefix = `ON`;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql> set global innodb_file_format = `BARRACUDA`;
mysql> set global innodb_large_prefix = `ON`;
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Although the code may speak for itself providing some details would help improve the quality of your answer!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Mysql 8.0^, I got this error while trying to do **PHP artisan migrate** on laravel 9
To solve it go to Wamp server hover on Mysql, open and edit  **my.ini**
[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtUGW.png)
Change `default-storage-engine=MYISAM` to `default-storage-engine=InnoDB`
[that's the final setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C4Eo.png)

SAVE IT AND RESTART ALL SERVICES

Comment: This one worked for me. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to use **MySQL Configuration File**

Change this to

```
innodb-default-row-format=compact
```

this

```
innodb-default-row-format=dynamic
```

[image]

Read: [**"Using Option Files"** from dev.mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html)