# Neos CMS (mysql 5.7+) and Typo3 4.5 on the same server?

Tags: mysql, typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-8.x, neoscms

I want to try out Neos CMS, which requires mysql 5.7+ or MariaDB 10.2+ or PostgreSQL 9.6+.

On our web server (it is a managed server), there is only mysql 5.6 available, and the server hosts many websites, including pages using Typo3 4.5, 6.2 and 8.7. The mysql database is globally configured, so any change done to the database will effect every single page.

According to one of the developers of Neos CMS, this is the reason why mysql 5.6 is required:

> The problem is that [mysql] 5.6 has a problem with utf8mb4 and length of indices. you could use 5.6 if you reconfigured that, so if you have access to the mysql config you might get away with that

According to 
[mysql change innodb_large_prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847015/mysql-change-innodb-large-prefix#35851332) you have to change four settings to reconfigure mysql 5.6 to work with utf8mb4 / indices:

- SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
- SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=ON;
- ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC; -- or COMPRESSED (goes on end of CREATE)
- innodb_large_prefix=1

Assuming I would do these changes - will these changes have bad effects on older pages like Typo3 4.5/6.2/8.7? Any chance that I install Neos CMS parallel to Typo3 4.5/6.2/8.7 instances?

Comment: If you're just trying it out, you should really spin it up in on isolated machine. You can probably do the kind of testing you want by spinning up an instance on AWS; for testing purposes, it may not cost you anything as you may not even use enough server resource to go above the free tier.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp with AWS, I'll check this out! However, if the test is successful, the problem will rise again, so I would still be happy if someone can give me some hints or even an answer :)